# External .js file can't get the page element?

Tags: javascript, html, external

I have an HTML page, and a separate .js file that is included in the page with a `<script src="...">` tag.

here is my .js file:

```
element = document.getElementById("test");
function sayTest() {
    alert(element.innerHTML);
}
```

When I place this code in the `<script>` tag on the html page, it works fine.
When I place this code in an external .js file, and include it with a `<script src="...">` tag, it does not work.

***Why is the second way not working, and how can I resolve that?***

Comment: It may probably have to do with the loading of the js file. Where in your HTML tree are you calling that script tag? Try calling it right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: just test & put an alert('Test') in 1st line of code in the external script. Where on the page is it loading in header or footer?

Comment: @PatoBeltran In both scenarios, the <script> tage is at the end of the body

Comment: @Victor2748 is the file even getting called? Like if you put the alert outside the function, does it shows up? If not, then your issue is inside the HTML, if yes, then the issue is in calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The Javascript is probably running before the DOM has loaded all the content.</s>

You should be able to wrap that so that it runs after the DOM has loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  element = document.getElementById("test");
  function sayTest() {
    alert(element.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

<s>Where are you actually calling the sayTest function?  If I run the following it works fin</s>

```
element = document.getElementById("test");
function sayTest() {
  alert(element.innerHTML);
}
sayTest();
```

With the information you have given.  The following should work.

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="sayTest()">Click Me!</button>
        <p id="test">Hello World!</p>

        <script src="script.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js file

```
element = document.getElementById("test");
function sayTest() {
    alert(element.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Do I put this code in the external .js that I have?

Comment: I run the sayTest() method when a button is clicked

Comment: Can you post the HTML?  I have a simple test working, I need to see more code to help

Answer (score 1):

try using like this:may be you have element in the exeterna.js use somewhere.
check the file path you are adding and see if the file is added properly.

```
function sayTest() {
var element = document.getElementById("test");
    alert(element.innerHTML);
}

call sayTest() onclick.
```